# What is a good job site to get a job abroad with a PhD degree?

Tags: working-visas, job-hunting

I am currently having serious depression. I have been applying to lots of jobs online. I want to get a job abroad with a doctorate degree in engineering. I am flexible to work in academia or in industry.

I think I have applied to almost 50 places, both industry and academic position, but for none of them I passed document screening. I didn't get a single interview.

I am looking for a job with working visa sponsorship in the civil engineering field.

Any help or idea? I do not have any preference, any country is fine. I am Indonesian by the way, so any country is fine.

Comment: It is not very unusual that people send a way more than one hundred resumes in the **country of their residence** to get a job. So having sent just 50 **from abroad** shouldn't be a reason for depression.

Comment: Are you only applying to jobs that specifically state they offer visa sponsorship?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I'm not answering the question, but a piece of advice.

If you have applied to 50+ places without any replies, than something is probably wrong either with your resume/profile or your job search strategy. Trying to apply in a different country is unlikely to work: landing a job as a foreigner is significantly harder: the hiring company would have to deal with relocation, visa sponsorship, lots of paperwork, etc.

Maybe you can hop over  to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ and post details of your resume and job search for advice on how to improve the results. If there is a big red flag on your resume, perhaps people can help you find and mitigate it.

Comment: For academia it can be normal in some fields. But I agree that it's OP's strategy which may need to change, also.
To OP: there is no one specific 'job search site' that works for everyone in every specialty. For academic jobs, you will need to look on academic job search websites specific to your field. There's AJO, astronomy has the AAS jobs register, high energy physics has INSPIRE-HEP... it depends what your specialty is in engineering. If RF or EE, your applications will be quite cross-disciplinary indeed (my field intersects with this)